# Using Multithreading two threads return same value with different inputs?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Hello I am ne to multithreading and trying to incorporate it into my program in order to get a particular calculation to converge faster. But when I create the two threads like below

```
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(() => { p0 = f(changePoint, result); });
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(() => { p1 = f(changePoint + 1, result); });
        firstThread.Start();
        secondThread.Start();
        firstThread.Join();
        secondThread.Join();
```

the values in p0 and p1 are the same(p0 has the same value as p1). Now if i take away the multithreading and just call them like this:

```
        p0 = f(changePoint, result);
        p1 = f(changePoint + 1, result);
```

different values are returned and everything works correctly.

What am i missing?

code of f(x,y)

```
public double f(double x,double result)
    {

        double temp = PCAcont.Future2Yrs(x).Last().FirstOrDefault().StatNetWorthToAssets.GetValueOrDefault();
        return temp - result;

    }
```

the main method

```
public double SecantMethod(double prec, int stepsCutoff, double changePoint, double result)
    {
        double p2, p1 = 0, p0 = 0;
        int i;

        Thread firstThread = new Thread(() => { p0 = f(changePoint, result); });
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(() => { p1 = f(changePoint + 1, result); });
        firstThread.Start();
        secondThread.Start();
        firstThread.Join();
        secondThread.Join();

        //p0 = f(changePoint, result);
        //p1 = f(changePoint + 1, result);
        p2 = p1 - f(p1, result) * (p1 - p0) / (f(p1, result) - f(p0, result));

        for (i = 0; System.Math.Abs(p2 - p1) > prec && i < stepsCutoff; i++)
        {
            p0 = p1;
            p1 = p2;
            p2 = p1 - f(p1, result) * (p1 - p0) / (f(p1, result) - f(p0,result));
        }
        if (i < stepsCutoff)
            return p2;
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}.The method did not converge", p2);
            return double.NaN;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `f(x,y)`? Or at least tell us what type `result` is, and whether it is modified inside `f()`?

Comment: Added f(x,y) in the main

Comment: Also, is that the exact code you're running? If your actual code is a for loop with each iteration setting up and starting a thread, the problem could have to do with how you're declaring and using p0 & p1.

Comment: no p0 and p1 are calculated before the for loop iterations

Comment: Also Changepoint is getting passed into the method it is not a value from the loop iteration

Comment: If you have a closure (your `{ p1 = f(changePoint + 1, result); }`) inside a loop, there are some non-intuitive things that can go on. If a loop is involved you should show your actual code.

Comment: I have included the actual method in the main so you can see what is going on

Comment: If you debug f does it receive different values for X?

Comment: Is the computation of `temp` in `f(x,y)`  dependant of time? How long does it take to compute `f(x,y)`?

Comment: blam it does receive different values for x but but looks like its only taking the value of the second(changePoint + 1) for both. didierc no it is not dependant on time, it does a about 3-40 seconds since I am using some foward recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comment only taking the second.

Look at this

PCAcont.Future2Yrs(x).Last().FirstOrDefault().StatNetWorthToAssets.GetValueOrDefault();

PCAcont is not locked and you are getting the result of the second X.
You need to lock.
And lock past the return as possibly the linq is deferred.